# Shutdown without sudo user password in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, shutdown

I'm setting up a minimalistic ubuntu based system with openbox as a window manager. Unlike the more full functioned window managers, there's no single click shutdown option. While i can shutdown using cli - this needs me to use sudo, and well, this isn't what i want. Is there any way to make the halt or poweroff commands work for any user, without the need for a password?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Run `visudo` and add `%users  ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /sbin/poweroff, /sbin/reboot`

So you can run `sudo poweroff` or `sudo reboot` without enter the user password.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure ACPI to trigger a shutdown when the power button is pressed. 
In Ubuntu this is the default behavior if nothing else is running that handles the power management. Have a look at `/etc/acpi/powerbtn.sh`.