# Ubuntu 15.04: suspend from console without sudo

Tags: linux, ubuntu, sudo, suspend, dbus

For years I have been able to suspend my Ubuntu-based machine from regular account using

```
dbus-send --system --print-reply --dest="org.freedesktop.UPower" /org/freedesktop/UPower org.freedesktop.UPower.Suspend
```

This no longer works in Ubuntu 15.04, where the following is reported:

```
Error org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod: Method "Suspend" with signature "" on interface "org.freedesktop.UPower" doesn't exist
```

One option to suspend without password prompt is to [edit `sudoers`](https://superuser.com/questions/92925/shutdown-without-sudo-user-password-in-ubuntu) and then `sudo pm-suspend`. Are there any other ways that do not involve granting root privileges?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try `systemctl suspend` That worked for me.

Comment: See also http://askubuntu.com/a/613814/43344 .