# have a bash script remotely shutdown another computer on the lan

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, shutdown, remote-shutdown

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to shut down a computer having a particular IP address?](https://superuser.com/questions/57705/how-to-shut-down-a-computer-having-a-particular-ip-address)

Hi I want to write a bash script that when called shuts down another computer on the lan. Maybe using ssh? The other computer is an ubuntu machine. Now I'm not sure how to send e.g. a

```
sudo shutdown -h now
```

command from withing a bash script to the ssh after logging in. Also I'm not sure how to obtain the rights for the sudo command, hence how to handle the communication between the server and client from within a bash script. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: A warning: anyone who posts `ssh root@computername /sbin/shutdown` without explaining how to circumvent requiring root SSH access will get my downvote ;-). Still, I think "How to shut down a computer having a particular IP address?" at http://superuser.com/questions/57705/how-to-shut-down-a-computer-having-a-particular-ip-address is a duplicate, so I guess answers should be posted at that other question.